# Recovering the Project after SVN update

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have done lot of changes in the project added new jars, modified the system libraries, added new folders. Everything was working fine but when I updated my project all seems to crash.

After the update I just cleaned and built the project.

All the packages are got corrupted and are getting rendered directly in project explorer.

I am not able to build the project.

The error I'm getting is as follow's>

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project    KerioCIProjectPortal        Unknown Java Problem

Comment: Can you rebase your project to previous stable rev and check - does it builds?

Comment: Did you check the SVN log to see what the latest commits that you pulled did to the project? Its a good rule not to check IDE-specific files into the repository but it does not stop some devs doing it if there are no ignore rules, - this might also have caused a problem to your Eclipse project config.

Comment: Make sure the source folders are properly mapped and the JRE (or JDK)  is set as Library. You can find those settings right clicking the project -> Properties, and going to section named Java Build Path.

Comment: The actual problem is like mentioned here http://dev-answers.blogspot.in/2009/06/eclipse-build-errors-javalangobject.html

Comment: but in my case the package structure is also got corrupted and all the packages are getting displayed on the main window,... So I just wanted undo the updates and bring back my working project is it possible?